# Put the value of an input Button next to the button via css

Tags: css, button

I was wondering if this is possible:
if I have an input field:

```
<input type="button" value="some value" class="icon-button" />
```

and it is styled with gradient background, border, box-shadow, etc.

I want to have the button like an Icon with all its style and the value-text right next to it.
I thought of something like this, but it didn't work:

```
.icon-button{
    display:block;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
/* gradients, borders, shadows, etc. */
   text-indent: 30px;
   overflow: visible;
}
```

Any Idea? I know I could solve it with javascript, but I would like to know if there is a css way to do this.

Comment: Can you provide a visual of what you're trying to achieve? And are you able to amend the markup if necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you're going to achieve this (at least not very neatly) using an input. If you can amend your markup to use an actual button to submit though, it's [pretty trivial](http://jsfiddle.net/cherryflavourpez/ktZJg/):

```
<button type="submit">Some value</button>
```

CSS:

```
button {
    line-height: 25px;
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
}

button::before {
    content: '';
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    margin-right: 3px;
/* gradients, borders, shadows, etc. */
    background: red;
}
```

You could use a `span` rather than generated content if IE7 support is needed. This approach is not possible with an `input`, as that can't contain any elements, nor can it have generated content.

If you *need* to use an input, you could achieve the same thing by wrapping it in a span and styling that.